# Dotnet Build Error: Unexpected character '�'

Tags: .net-core, encoding, localization, ubuntu-20.04

When I pull my project from Git into my Ubuntu 20.04 server and try to build the project, I get the following error:

```
Build FAILED.
/home/brian/Project/Program.cs(15,37): error CS1002: ; expected
```

Program.cs line 15

```
using Project.Services.Ingrediënten;
```

Becomes this on Ubuntu20.04

```
using Project.Services.Ingredi�nten;
```

I'm assuming it has something to do with the character 'ë'

However, when I try to build the project on my CentOS8 instance, there is no issue

CentOS8 locale settings:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Ubuntu 20.04 locale settings:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

File encoding on CentOS8

```
Startup.cs: C++ source, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text, with very long lines
```

File encoding on Ubuntu20.04

```
Startup.cs: ISO-8859 text
```

Am I missing something on the Ubuntu 20.04 instance ? Kind regards

Comment: There are _different_ files `Startup.cs`. Ensure that the file on Ubuntu is `UTF-8` encoded…

Comment: Is there a way to default encode to UTF-8?